# Is there a way for WebGL/THREE.js to read a video DOM element into YUV textures?

Tags: javascript, video, three.js, webgl, yuv

In most platform specific APIs, there is an option to read the video frame as it's native pixel format, YUV.
However, the DOM Video Element wrapped with a `THREE.Texture`, always returns RGB.
Is there a way to get textures in the native pixel format of YUV?

I am using JS and THREE.js, but if it's possible in WebGL, that's also good.

Answer (score 1):

There is the incoming [Web codecs API](https://wicg.github.io/web-codecs) which should expose a [Plane interface](https://wicg.github.io/web-codecs/#plane-interface) from where we should be able to read the YUV (already available for testing in Chrome 86, under a flag).

This is all still very experimental, it's still not well defined how this can then be used with webgl, though it is [apparently already doable](https://github.com/WICG/web-codecs/issues/88#issuecomment-706825298) (I personally don't know how), but there will definitely be some work in the near future around that, you can follow [this repo](https://github.com/WICG/web-codecs) for more info.

Comment: Note that [according to this](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5669293909868544) Apple has currently said they are against this API

Comment: @gman, I'm not sure what w3c's policy is exactly, but for whatwg they only need two implementers interested to publish the specs, I guess w3c is similar here.

Comment: There's specs and then there's reality. If Apple doesn't support it then 60-70% of mac users and 100% of iOS users won't have it. And even if Firefox is positive on it the odds of them implementing it are not 100%. They've said yes to tons of specs but don't appear to have to manpower or desire to actually implement them. Examples: OffscreenCanvas, 2d canvas in workers, image-rendering: pixelated, deviceContentBox in ResizeObserver, and many others. In any case, I'm only trying to pointing out to the questioner that this solution may require a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Or at least the browser itself provides no API to get video data in YUV format.

Comment: Actually, there will most probably be something: https://github.com/WICG/web-codecs/issues/88#issuecomment-706825298

Comment: Why don't you just leave an answer if you disagree with this one?

Comment: Because I lack the push to webgl part, but fair enough, I added my 2 cents.